# Is my choice of Wowza Edge EC2 instance correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wowza, wowza-transcoder

[image]

My understanding of building a HTTP Cache Edge on wowza are as follow :

1. More memory == more concurrent devices
2. Storage speed must equal to bandwidth speed ( SSD is a must )
3. Provided I'm using 80% of allocated dedicated 10G bandwidth,each instance should be able to server at least 5000 devices for 720p@1500kbps stream, right ?

Comment: Seems like you might want to look at leveraging CloudFront to avoid some server cost and concentrating this much bandwidth in a single region.  Possibly useful: https://www.wowza.com/docs/cloudfront-integration

Answer (score 0):

1. Like Michael commented, using Wowza Streaming Engine as a Cloudfront origin will very likely solve your dilemma. Assuming you only have a single 720p stream, you can use your Wowza Transcoder as the Cloudfront origin.
2. Watch the "Server monitoring" tab while scaling load up to estimate memory and CPU requirements. Consider scaling out or up if your CPU, heap, or total memory usage crosses 50% utilization regularly.
3. Storage isn't impacted much during Wowza transcoding or streaming. The live caches are in memory. For recording or DVR applications, yes, low latency IOPS from SSD are very useful and would otherwise overload EBS.
4. Cloudfront should mitigate your bandwidth issues, but in general on AWS I wouldn't expect to get much more than 80% of quoted bandwidth.